# Native Autoload is Not Recognized by Web Host

Tags: php, codeigniter

I added one the following snippet in my config.php:

```
 /*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Native Autoload - by Phil Sturgeon. New Version!
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Nothing to do with config/autoload.php, this allows PHP autoload to work
| for base controllers and some third-party libraries.
|
| If using HMVC you do not need this! HMVC will autoload.
|
| Place this code at the bottom of your application/config/config.php file.
*/
function __autoload($class)
{
    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . 'php'))
        {
            include $file;
        }
        elseif (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $class . 'php'))
        {
            include $file;
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, i found that my web host throw an error; the above code only works on my localhost xampp!

When i run my page from the remote web host i get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Frontend_Controller' not found in ....***some path***..../ci_centric/application/controllers/home.php on line 16
```

**Paths:**

> Frontend_Controller extends MY_Controller
>
> MY_Controller resides in core and Frontend_Controller resides in libraries
>
> Home controller extends Frontend_Controller

***Wondering why it doesn't work in my web host but works fine in localhost! Do i need to edit php.ini? Please advise.***

Remote web host has PHP version 5.2.*

Comment: If you `die` or `print_r` the `$file` variable within your `__autoload` function, is the path correct? Out of interest, what version of PHP does your development server have?

Comment: It doesn't even echo anything. I keep getting the same Fatal Error posted above! Odd... The tech guy told me PHP version 5.2.*. However, i doubt it; i'll have to confirm.

Comment: Could be worth doing a `phpinfo` to confirm ;)

Comment: Is that the version on your dev or production server? Are they both above 5? It could be worth, commenting out the `include` lines within your `__autoload` and implement the `die/print_r` and see what is returned.

Comment: Production server is PHP Version 5.2.17. My development server is 5.3.1

Comment: Aha! I tacked this at the end:

else {
   echo "Ops"; die();
  }

I got the output "Ops" ... Wondering why my production server doesn't hit the first or second if condition? In my development everything works fine.

Comment: Ops! Another problem. When i added else { echo "Ops"; die(); } to my development server, i also got the output Ops ... Strange

Comment: Its ok. I will see what i can do. Either way, i will have to remove the else { } part.

Comment: I already upgraded the production server to 5.3.*. No errors are shown but the page appears BLANK. Will see what i can do.

Comment: If you have upgraded, you might find your `display_errors` is turned off as a result of updating your `php.ini`. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of your script.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15586/discussion-between-user311509-and-gavin)